# google custom search engine not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, search, google-custom-search

I have add Google Custom Search Engine On My Website and It was working Perfectly.

But Now it some time doesn't return anything something like google's custom search engine JavaScript does not get executed.

link [Link where search console is added](https://booksmotion.com/ssep/search.php?q=Raj)

on link it will give some results refresh it or try searching something else search box and search results both would not appear

i have tested it some 10+ time and it some time not work 40% i don't know what's the issue.

no massage script error message in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning of Rocket Loader in Cloudflare fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google 'Programmable Search Engine' with CloudFlare, add `data-cfasync="false"` attibure to the `<script>` tag to make it work:

```
<script async data-cfasync="false" src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

Otherwise it may not work correctly with no or blank display.